# How to get rid of local JSON manipulation

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax

Intro: I know that working with local JSON is not the standard, but I'm learning, and I find it easier than create a server etc..

I have this json file:

```
{
"General": {
    "CloseTime": "20:00:00-23:30:00",
    "GeneralActive": "1"
},
"SpecialDays": {
    "SpecialWeekDaysTime": "16:30:00-23:30:00",
    "Sunday": "0",
    "Monday": "0",
    "Tuesday": "0",
    "Wednesday": "0",
    "Thursday": "0",
    "Friday": "0",
    "Saturday": "0",
    "TotalSpecificDays": "1",
    "Day1": "05\/10\/2016 09:30:00-07\/10\/2016 12:45:00"
},
"GeneralAdd": {
    "CloseTime": "21:00:00-23:30:00",
    "GeneralAddActive": "1"
},
"SpecialDaysAdd": {
    "SpecialWeekDaysTimeAdd": "16:30:00-23:30:00",
    "Sunday": "0",
    "Monday": "0",
    "Tuesday": "0",
    "Wednesday": "0",
    "Thursday": "0",
    "Friday": "0",
    "Saturday": "0",
    "TotalSpecificDays": "0",
    "Day1": "01\/01\/0001 00:00:00-01\/01\/0001 03:00:00",
    "Day2": "01\/01\/0001 00:00:00-01\/01\/0001 03:00:00"
},
"Scripts": {
    "Enabled": "1",
     [etc..]
}
```

Having an HTML form, I need to modify fields values in the file, after an user filled text into the web page. I think to be doing it logically right, but suddenly I saw that "SpecialDays" and "SpecialDaysAdd" both have days as key, how can I access to the file distinguishing different keys?

Am I accessing the document in the right way?

Am I correctly retrieving info from html?

This is my js code for now:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="data.json"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var opTime;
var clTime; 
var contOpen; 
var contClos;
var specialDays = [];
var aggDays = [];

var days = 7;     
for (var i = 0; i < days; i++) {
  specialDays.push(false);
  aggDays.push(false);
}

var opTime = document.getElementById("openTimeField").value;
var clTime = document.getElementById("closedTimeField").value; 
var contOpen = document.getElementById("openContinuedField").value; 
var contClos = document.getElementById("closedContinuedField").value; 


var specialDays = [
    document.getElementById("spMonCheck").checked,
    document.getElementById("spTueCheck").checked,
    document.getElementById("spWedCheck").checked,
    document.getElementById("spThuCheck").checked,
    document.getElementById("spFriCheck").checked,
    document.getElementById("spSatCheck").checked,
    document.getElementById("spSunCheck").checked
];

var aggDays = [
    document.getElementById("aggMonCheck").checked,
    document.getElementById("aggTueCheck").checked,
    document.getElementById("aggWedCheck").checked,
    document.getElementById("aggThuCheck").checked,
    document.getElementById("aggFriCheck").checked,
    document.getElementById("aggSatCheck").checked,
    document.getElementById("aggSunCheck").checked
];


text = localStorage.getItem("data.json");
obj = JSON.parse(text);

obj.getElementById("CloseTime").value = clTime.concat(opTime);
obj.getElementById("SpecialWeekDaysTime").value = opTime.concat(clTime);
obj.getElementById("Sunday").value= 
obj.getElementById("Monday").value=
obj.getElementById("Tuesday").value=
obj.getElementById("Wednesday").value=
obj.getElementById("Thursday").value=
obj.getElementById("Friday").value=
obj.getElementById("Sunday").value=
</script>
```

I don't know if I'm doing it right, and how to move forward, send help

I'm a beginner, but I think everyone will notice reading my code, thank you in advance!

Comment: JSON is a string. Once you pass it through `JSON.parse`, it's an object, and you access it just like any other object, use `object.property`. `getElementById` is for accessing DOM/HTML elements, not object properties. You've got a couple problems though. You're referencing the JSON file as a script (`src="data.json"`), which would load the file and try and execute it as a script, which won't work. Likewise, `localStorage.get('data.json')` will likely return `null`, since it hasn't been  set previously.

Comment: So I just delete the line, and will work? It's in the same folder with the js file 
Also, getElementById has a duplicate in "SpecialDays" and "SpecialDaysAdd", it is fine to access like it is?

Comment: Honestly, you should really take a while and go back to basics. Find tutorials online on JavaScript and JSON. Stack Overflow is not a good place for teaching people so much of the basics.

Comment: thanks for the advice, I am, just one week into js, I'm learning alone so I thought that an internet community about coding could have helped me learning faster, like explaining me errors and stuffs. Sorry about that, I have a wrong concept about communities

Comment: Just this community :). Take the [tour], read [ask]. Those explain what this community is for and about. Additionally, there are many other sites on the internet besides Stack Overflow. Hard to believe I know.

Comment: Already read the rules obviusly, by the way: you are not the only one that can read and write, plus behaving like the God-chosen programmer it's not exactely commmunity-friendly, get down, if you don't like a question, don't answer it. It's not written in the rules, but it's a good life rule, try to follow it. It will help yourself and people around you too!
Anyway, I did nothing wrong about the question, if you think otherwise, you can ask a moderator to delete the post instead of arguing. :)

Comment: I think the reason Mike kind of gave up on teaching you is because you weren't demonstrating much knowledge of JavaScript object properties.  That's fine if you're learning, but since these are explained in many places across the web, someone would be duplicating lots of teaching effort to give a one-on-one explanation to you. Stack Overflow mostly focuses on providing individual attention to someone when they have a 90%-working scenario, but one very unique problem with it. I think Mike felt quite a lot of your program's design had to change for it to work.

Comment: I tried to search in this site and others, documentation and w3school courses, but I'm still stucked for two days now, so I tried to ask, I think politely a question on this site. I agree that I'm way too far from being a programmer, but I still want to try. I'll avoid further questions tho. By the way, thanks for the comment, I appreciate politeness :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to convert your JSON string to an object:

```
var jsonObject= JSON.parse(jsonString);
```

… then you will have access to `jsonObject.SpecialDaysAdd.Monday`

later, you could assign the value like this:

```
jsonObject.SpecialDaysAdd.Monday = "TEST";
```

once this is made you have to convert the JSON object back to a string like so:

```
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(jsonObject);
```

this will convert the JSON object to a string that you can send, store, etc.

Comment: text = localStorage.getItem("data.json");
obj = JSON.parse(text);

obj.getElementById("OrarioChiusura").value = clTime.concat(opTime);

I did it already I think(?)
But I understood that I have to
obj.something.something to acess fields into JSON obj, thanks! 
I'll try to figure it out